# get arguments passed and put it in an array

Tags: ksh, array, arguments

is there a way to make the arguments passed become the element of an array?

I want to access those arguments individually through array.

like this:

```
./script.ksh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

then it will become like this:

```
element[0]=arg1
element[1]=arg2
element[2]=arg3
```

Comment: You know they are already in `$1`, `$2`..., right?

Answer (score 4):

They are already in an array, the array of positional parameters `$@`  with individual elements accessed with `$1`, `$2`... (start at `1`, `$0` is the script name).

Note that there are several implementations (and versions thereof) of `ksh`: AT&T ksh88 (as found in most commercial Unices), AT&T ksh93 (made open source in 2000, sometimes found as `dtksh` on commercial Unices and as an optional package on opensource unix-likes), pdksh and its derivatives (MirBSD `ksh`, OpenBSD `ksh`) which was the only `ksh` available on opensource Unix-likes before 2000 and `zsh` (when called as `ksh`).

To assign to another array, with `ksh88` (also works with all other implementations of `ksh` except older `pdksh`):

```
set -A array -- "$@"
```

With older versions of pdksh:

```
set -A array "$@"
```

With ksh93, zsh and recent versions of `mksh`:

```
array=("$@")
```

Comment: The `=(…)` syntax is supported in no `pdksh` version, only `mksh`. (And the original AT&T Korn Shell, of course.)

Comment: @mirabilos Well, that's what I meant by newer `pdksh`, as `mksh` is where the development of `pdksh` variant of `ksh` is happening. I suppose `oksh` merges features from `mksh` as well, doesn't it? If you prefer I make a distinction on the name, or if you have a generic name for the pdksh family of shells, like `pdksh` and its derivatives, let me know.

Comment: No, neither OpenBSD nor Deli Linux merge `mksh` changes into their oksh flavour generally. The latter tried but violated the licence, so they had to revert that change after I pointed that out to them. (As a European Citizen, I have to choose a proper OSS licence for my code.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat t.ksh
#!/bin/ksh

element=( "$@" )

echo "${element[0]}"
echo "${element[1]}"
echo "${element[2]}"
```

.

```
$ ./t.ksh one two three
one
two
three
```

Although I don't understand why you would want to do that, the positional parameters are readily available in `$@` which you can easily iterate over.